# Illustrator: Make a compound path a single path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, pathfinder

I have the letter "a" expanded as two paths, one being the letter and the other being the circle inside of the "a"

[image: a]

I need to get the "a" to be a single, simple path. When I use pathfinder > minus front, I get the desired result but as a compound path.

[image: a2]

Is there any way to get the compound path to be just a path?

Thanks!

Comment: is there a specific reason why you need a single path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. That's the long and the short of it. As soon as a path consists of more than one continuous line, it has to be a compound path.